# For what $t$, $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are monotonic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of ODE in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
$\frac{dy}{dx}=AY,Y(0)=\left(\begin{array}{}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right),t>0$ 
 where $A=\left(\begin{array}{}
-1&& 1\\
0 && -1
\end{array}\right)$ and $Y(t)=\left(\begin{array}{}
y_1(t)\
y_2(t)
\end{array}\right)$$. Then

1. $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are monotonically increasing for $t>0.$
2. $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are monotonically increasing for $t>1$.
3. $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are monotonically decreasing for $t>0$.
4. $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are monotonically decreasing for $t>1$.

The Given Matrix has $-1$ as eigenvalue and $(0,1)$ and (1,0) are the eigenvector. The second vector (generalized eigenvector) we can choose any thing that is independent of first one because $(A+I)^2$ is zero matrix. How to proceed next?

Comment: then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are decreasing on $t>0.$ If so then option $4$ also correct but exactly only one is the correct option

Answer (score 1):

*$Hint:$* $y_1=te^{-t}$ and $y_2=e^{-t}$ are solutions and $y_1$ has a maximum at $t=1$.